# beamer/beamerarticle: mode specification for frame doesn't work as expected

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

In the following example the `\section` comand (and its argument) is ignored as expected. But not all the content of the frame: The text and the first \tikz are not printed but the unknown color gives two errors (as do also unknown commands) and the graphics appears on the page (eso-pic is needed to get this effect). A `\stepcounter{section}` in the frame is executed too.

I also tested the other way round: A `\begin{frame}<article>` in a beamer document: This doesn't work either. Is this a bug? (There is no problem if I use explicit `\mode` commands.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\framegraphic[1]%
  {\AddToShipoutPictureFG
   {\AtPageCenter
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#1}%
  }}}


\begin{document}
blabla

\section<presentation>{This section exists 
  \tikz\draw[color=unknowncolorA] (1,1)rectangle (0,0); 
 only in the presentation modes}

\begin{frame}<presentation>
  some text
 \tikz\draw[fill=red] (1,1)rectangle (0,0);
 \tikz\draw[color=unknowncolorB] (1,1)rectangle (0,0);
 \framegraphic{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Updated answer after full analysis]

Although the behaviour is perhaps not obvious, it is I think by design (certainly I'm extremely reluctant to alter it.). The relevant code lines in `beamerbaseframe` are

```
\long\def\beamer@@frame<#1>[#2]{%
  \global\let\insertframetitle=\@empty%
  \global\let\insertframesubtitle=\@empty%
  \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
  \refstepcounter{framenumber}%
  \beamer@slideinframe=0\relax%
  \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
  {\beamer@masterdecode{#1}}%
  \ifbeamer@anotherslide%
    \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@dosingleframe%
  \else% no slides in frame
    \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@donoframe%
  \fi%
  \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
  \beamer@howtotreatframe}
```

In particular, notice `\beamer@donoframe`: this is quite correctly set as the action to take. However, what's non-obvious is that 'gobbling' a frame works by typesetting it into a box which is not then used. For that reason we need the commands *in* the box to be defined.

Given that the way the `beamer`/`beamerarticle`  split works really starts from the assumption that the document will 'somewhere' define everything, I think this is 'perhaps odd but intentional'.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/256/beamer-beamerarticle-mode-specification

Comment: I think `beamer` intentionally processes excluded frames (through `\beamer@donoframe`, putting them into `\beamer@tempbox`) so that side effects can still happen. Regardless, the most obvious difference between `\mode<handout>{\begin{frame}Text\end{frame}` and `\begin{frame}<handout>Text\end{frame}` is the frame numbering in non-`handout` mode, so the two specifications aren't intended to produce the same result.

Comment: @cyberSingularity Yup, having thought about it properly you are spot on!